# How can I get the array index from a button php

Tags: php, arrays, button

i have an array with objects that i have submitted to display in the form with foreach, i did it like that:

```
<?php session_start(); if(isset($_SESSION['objectList'])){
foreach($_SESSION['objectList'] as $object){
    ?>
     <form action="control.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="op" value="-" /> <?php echo $object;?>
    </form>
<?php } 
}else{
echo "No hay objetos";
}
?>
```

When the "-" button is pressed, the position of the array of that button must be eliminated, that is done with the following code in another class:

```
unset($_SESSION['objectList'][$object]);
$_SESSION['objectList']=array_values($_SESSION['objectList']);
```

But I do not know how to send the index value of the pressed button

It looks like this
[empty array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHgsf.png)
[3 object in the array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSEuX.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add the index as a hidden input like this:

```
<?php session_start(); if(isset($_SESSION['objectList'])){
foreach($_SESSION['objectList'] as $index => $object){
    ?>
     <form action="control.php" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="index" value="<?= $index; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="op" value="-" /> <?php echo $object;?>
    </form>
<?php } 
}else{
echo "No hay objetos";
}
?>
```

the index is then in the $_POST variable `$_POST['index']`

But be carefull if you use a numeric index, because if you unset it, then the indexes might not be correct anymore. Better use a associative array.

Comment: Using the session array index seems wrong to me. I would think doing a search for the value to remove the value-containing array item, or using an associative array with `array(uniqid() => $object)` in construction would be better suited for the task (in general).

Comment: @Jared yes that could be a problem

Comment: thanks @Sepultura, I could solve it by adding $ index => $ object in the foreach and with the input hidden to send the index, now i can add and remove correctly.

Comment: thanks @Jared, I will investigate about the method uniqid(), it looks interesting